# redirect to async login method from async register in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-identity-2

I have register method which is like

```
public async Task<ActionResult> O365Login()
```

and two login method

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
```

Now i want to redirect to `asynch login` method but when i'm writing `return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");` this will return to my `public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)`.
can someone help me with the syntax to redirect to `asynch login` method

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the issue. The question in its current state is not providing enough information to reproduce the stated problem.

Answer (score 0):

`RedirectToAction` should work the way you call it - it issues HTTP 301 redirect. And it does not matter where it redirects you to sync or async.

You need to understand that `RedirectToAction` does not call `Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)` directly withing process. Redirect to action send a reply to a browser client saying "You should go to /Login/Account?params=blah`.